# Why my property is always empty in my custom qt widget

Tags: qt, properties, setter, getter, designer

I try to create a simple widget for Qt Designer. When I set a property and just after or a long time after when I try to read my property, she's always empty.

```
setProperty("iconConnection", QIcon("toto.png"));
qDebug() << property("iconConnection");
```

I try differents tests and all done nothing. Maybe I don't understand the concept of Q_PROPERTY

Full code:

QKSwitchButton.h

```
#pragma once

// Qt
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QState>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QtUiPlugin/QDesignerExportWidget>

class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT QKSwitchButton: public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QIcon      iconDisconnected          READ iconDisconnected       WRITE setIconDisconnected       NOTIFY iconDisconnectedChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QIcon      iconConnection            READ iconConnection         WRITE setIconConnection         NOTIFY iconConnectionChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QIcon      iconConnected             READ iconConnected          WRITE setIconConnected          NOTIFY iconConnectedChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QIcon      iconDisconnection         READ iconDisconnection      WRITE setIconDisconnection      NOTIFY iconDisconnectionChanged)

public:
    QKSwitchButton(QWidget * parent = 0);
    ~QKSwitchButton();

    QIcon iconDisconnected();
    QIcon iconConnection();
    QIcon iconConnected();
    QIcon iconDisconnection();

public slots:
    void setIconDisconnected(QIcon icon);
    void setIconConnection(QIcon icon);
    void setIconConnected(QIcon icon);
    void setIconDisconnection(QIcon icon);

signals:
    void iconDisconnectedChanged(QIcon icon);
    void iconConnectionChanged(QIcon icon);
    void iconConnectedChanged(QIcon icon);
    void iconDisconnectionChanged(QIcon icon);

private:
    QStateMachine* m_machine;
    QState *m_stateOFF;
    QState *m_stateConnection;
    QState *m_stateON;
    QState *m_stateDisconnection;

    QIcon m_iconDisconnected;
    QIcon m_iconConnection;
    QIcon m_iconConnected;
    QIcon m_iconDisconnection;

};
```

QKSwitchButton.cpp

```
#include "QKSwitchButton.h"

// Qt
#include <QState>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QEventTransition>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>

// 
#include "QKEvent.h"

#include <QMetaProperty>

#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

static void dump_props(QObject *o)
{
  auto mo = o->metaObject();
  qDebug() << "## Properties of" << o << "##";
  do {
    qDebug() << "### Class" << mo->className() << "###";
    std::vector<std::pair<QString, QVariant> > v;
    v.reserve(mo->propertyCount() - mo->propertyOffset());
    for (int i = mo->propertyOffset(); i < mo->propertyCount();
          ++i)
      v.emplace_back(mo->property(i).name(),
                     mo->property(i).read(o));
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (auto &i : v)
      qDebug() << i.first << "=>" << i.second;
  } while ((mo = mo->superClass()));
}

QKSwitchButton::QKSwitchButton(QWidget * parent)
    : QPushButton(parent)
{
    m_machine = new QStateMachine(this);

    this->setText("");

    // States
    m_stateOFF = new QState();    
    m_stateConnection = new QState();    
    m_stateON = new QState();
    m_stateDisconnection = new QState();


    // Changes of states

    QEventTransition *connectionTransition = new QEventTransition(this, QEvent::MouseButtonPress);
    connectionTransition->setTargetState(m_stateConnection );
    m_stateOFF->addTransition(connectionTransition);

    QKTransition *connectedTransition = new QKTransition(QKEvent::DeviceConnected );
    connectedTransition->setTargetState(m_stateON );
    m_stateConnection->addTransition( connectedTransition );

    QKTransition *connectionFailedTransition = new QKTransition(QKEvent::DeviceConnectionFailed);
    connectionFailedTransition->setTargetState(m_stateOFF);
    m_stateConnection->addTransition(connectionFailedTransition);

    QEventTransition *disconnectionTransition = new QEventTransition(this, QEvent::MouseButtonPress);
    disconnectionTransition->setTargetState(m_stateDisconnection);
    m_stateON->addTransition(disconnectionTransition);

    QKTransition *disconnectedTransition = new QKTransition(QKEvent::DeviceDisconnected );
    disconnectedTransition->setTargetState(m_stateOFF);
    m_stateDisconnection->addTransition(disconnectedTransition);

    m_machine->addState(m_stateON);
    m_machine->addState(m_stateOFF);
    m_machine->addState(m_stateConnection);
    m_machine->addState(m_stateDisconnection);

    //this->setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/ribbon/ON-OFF-off.png"));

    m_machine->setInitialState(m_stateOFF);

    m_machine->start();

}


QKSwitchButton::~QKSwitchButton()
{
}


QIcon QKSwitchButton::iconDisconnected()
{
    return m_iconDisconnected;
}
QIcon QKSwitchButton::iconConnection()
{
    return m_iconConnection;
}
QIcon QKSwitchButton::iconConnected()
{
    return m_iconConnected;
}
QIcon QKSwitchButton::iconDisconnection()
{
    return m_iconDisconnection;
}

void QKSwitchButton::setIconDisconnected(QIcon icon)
{
    dump_props(this);

    m_stateOFF->assignProperty(this, "icon", icon);
    const QMetaObject *mo = metaObject();
    QMetaProperty prop = mo->property(mo->indexOfProperty("iconConnection"));
    qDebug() << property(prop.name());
    qDebug() << "============================";


    setProperty("iconConnection", QIcon("toto.png"));
    qDebug() << property("iconConnection");

    emit iconDisconnectedChanged(icon);
}
void QKSwitchButton::setIconConnection(QIcon icon)
{
    m_stateConnection->assignProperty(this, "icon", icon);
    emit iconConnectionChanged(icon);
}
void QKSwitchButton::setIconConnected(QIcon icon)
{
    m_stateON->assignProperty(this, "icon", icon);
    emit iconConnectedChanged(icon);
}
void QKSwitchButton::setIconDisconnection(QIcon icon)
{
    m_stateDisconnection->assignProperty(this, "icon", icon);
    emit iconDisconnectionChanged(icon);
}
```

QKSwitchButtonPlugin.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtUiPlugin/QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface>

class QIcon;
class QWidget;

class QKSwitchButtonPlugin : public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.QDesignerCustomWidget")
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "com.toto.plugin.Qt.SwitchButton" FILE "QKSwitchButtonMetadata.json") // It's important to change the version name after every modification.
    Q_INTERFACES(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface)

public:
    explicit QKSwitchButtonPlugin(QObject *parent = 0);

    bool isContainer() const override;
    bool isInitialized() const override;
    QIcon icon() const override;
    QString domXml() const override;
    QString group() const override;
    QString includeFile() const override;
    QString name() const override;
    QString toolTip() const override;
    QString whatsThis() const override;
    QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent) override;
    void initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor) override;

private slots:
    void iconDisconnectedChanged(QIcon icon);
    /*void iconConnectionChanged(QIcon icon);
    void iconConnectedChanged(QIcon icon);
    void iconDisconnectionChanged(QIcon icon);*/

 private:
     bool initialized;
};
```

QKSwitchButtonPlugin.cpp:

```
#include <QtDesigner/QExtensionFactory>
#include <QtDesigner/QExtensionManager>
#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerFormEditorInterface>
#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerFormWindowInterface>
#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerContainerExtension>
#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerPropertySheetExtension>

#include <QIcon>
#include <QtPlugin>

#include "QKSwitchButton.h"
#include "QKSwitchButtonPlugin.h"

QKSwitchButtonPlugin::QKSwitchButtonPlugin(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , initialized(false)
{
}

QString QKSwitchButtonPlugin::name() const
{
    return QLatin1String("QKSwitchButton");
}

QString QKSwitchButtonPlugin::group() const
{
    return QLatin1String("toto");
}

QString QKSwitchButtonPlugin::toolTip() const
{
    return QString();
}

QString QKSwitchButtonPlugin::whatsThis() const
{
    return QString();
}

QString QKSwitchButtonPlugin::includeFile() const
{
    return QLatin1String("QKSwitchButton.h");
}

QIcon QKSwitchButtonPlugin::icon() const
{
    return QIcon();
}

bool QKSwitchButtonPlugin::isContainer() const
{
    return false;
}

QWidget *QKSwitchButtonPlugin::createWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    QKSwitchButton *widget = new QKSwitchButton(parent);
    connect(widget, &QKSwitchButton::iconDisconnectedChanged, this, &QKSwitchButtonPlugin::iconDisconnectedChanged);

    return widget;
}

bool QKSwitchButtonPlugin::isInitialized() const
{
    return initialized;
}

void QKSwitchButtonPlugin::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor )
{
    Q_UNUSED(formEditor)
    if (initialized)
        return;

    initialized = true;
}

QString QKSwitchButtonPlugin::domXml() const
{
    return QLatin1String("\
<ui language=\"c++\">\
    <widget class=\"QKSwitchButton\" name=\"qkswitchbutton\">\
        <property name=\"geometry\">\
            <rect>\
                <x>0</x>\
                <y>0</y>\
                <width>63</width>\
                <height>30</height>\
            </rect>\
        </property>\
    </widget>\
    <customwidgets>\
        <customwidget>\
            <class>QKSwitchButton</class>\
            <extends>QPushButton</extends>\
        </customwidget>\
    </customwidgets>\
</ui>");
}


void QKSwitchButtonPlugin::iconDisconnectedChanged(QIcon icon)
{
    setProperty("iconDisconnected", icon);
}
```

Comment: try with: `setProperty("iconConnection", QVariant::fromValue(QIcon("toto.png")));`

Comment: Thank, but not working

Comment: I recommend placing the icon path as absolute or within a resource.

Comment: with save data in member variable all works fine. so I think I don't understand the concept of Q_PROPERTY. At the beginning I thought that was necessarily the data is stored somewhere in the Q_PROPERTY. But it would seem that Q_PROPERTY acts same like abstract class.

Comment: Q_PROPERTY is a macro that creates certain necessary variables and methods automatically with the data that you provide. it is not an abstract class. for example he creates within it the method setProperty and property. Did my recommendation work?

Comment: Ok thank you. So it's not necessary to create a variable member ? Your recommendation didn't work.